# How do I convert windows 7 files to work in Ubuntu

Tags: files

I have a number of cd's with some of my windows 7 files, i.e Musical compositions/pictures and other data. Is there a way to convert them to be used with Ubuntu?

Comment: What formats of file they they?

Comment: They will not be **Windows 7** files, but rather common windows-based app. media file-types. ***Ubuntu** already has broader support and (free) utilities for obscure file-types and conversion than Windows 7.*

Comment: You will need to be more specific.  Pictures in ".jpg", ".tif", ".png" for example will just work Music in ".mid" will work.  ".mp3" needs you to install an additional package.

Answer (score 0):

Music (.MP3, .FLAC, .WAV etc), Documents (.TXT,.DOC,.DOCX,.XLS,.XLSX,.PPT,.PPTX,.PDF etc), Pictures (.PNG, .JPEG, .GIF, .TIF, .SVG etc) can all be used fine in Ubuntu. In fact, Ubuntu will take more different files than Windows 7. Computer files are not specific for any OS. What might not work out-of-the-box in Ubuntu are game files, since they will most likely be in [binary format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file), specifically for the game they were used for. But even this often works by using Wine or PlayOnLinux.